# Remove all files without a keyword in the filename

Tags: bash, files, filenames

I have a list of files in the following fashion:

```
> file1.jpg 
> file1_orig.jpg 
> file2.jpg 
> file2_orig.jpg
```

I want to keep all the files with the extension _orig.jpg and discard those without. How can this be achieved using bash?

Comment: Are they in a single directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Bash's [extended filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-matching_002c-pattern):

```
rm !(*_orig.jpg)
```

The `!(pattern)` syntax:

> Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

so this expands to all filenames that don't match `*_orig.jpg`, which you can delete (or move out of the way). You need to have the `extglob` option enabled, which you can do with [`shopt -s extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) beforehand (otherwise you will get an error of the form "event not found"). It is commonly enabled by default, though.

---

Alternatively, and portably, you can just move the files you want to keep out of the way temporarily and delete the rest:

```
mkdir tmp
mv *_orig.jpg tmp
rm *.jpg
mv tmp/*.jpg .
rmdir tmp
```

There are options using [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) as well:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*_orig.jpg' -exec rm '{}' +
```

That will find any (regular) files recursively in the current directory that are not named `*_orig.jpg` and delete them; this is your best (but not only) option if the files aren't all directly inside one directory.

Comment: Dammit, I was half through my answer. :) Just as an aside, you can check to see if extglob is enabled with `$ shopt | grep extglob`. Also `-execdir` is preferred for `find` for security reasons (see `man find`). Oh, and also you can check and make sure you've picked the right files before removing them with `ls !(*_orig.jpg)` and `find . -type f ! -name '*_orig.jpg'`. +1

Comment: `shopt extglob` will tell you directly. `-execdir` is a non-standard extension and doesn't really resolve any security issues here.

Comment: Good points. I didn't realise `-execdir` was non-POSIX and only GNU. FWIW here is a theoretical [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html) of an attack, which is admittedly unlikely here; however, I always use `-execdir` as good practice.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX way:

```
$ find . \( ! -name . -prune -a -name "*.jpg" -a ! -name "*_orig.jpg" \) -exec rm -- {} +
```